# PyQgis, Add field to attribute table and Output error

Tags: pyqgis, fields-attributes

I'm trying to code a script who calculate id of vineyard lines and vines in these lines.

I code with temporary layers, just my final layer will be save.
But I'm getting stuck on adding new fields, at line 39, I have an OUTPUT error, and QGIS log says no more.
Can you help me ?

This is my code :

```
##point_layer=vector
##Intervine_distance=number 1.5
##output_layer=output vector

import os, processing
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *

# Project Layer in L93

l93 = processing.runalg("qgis:reprojectlayer", point_layer, "EPSG:2154", None)

# Buffer

Dbuf=(Intervine_distance/2)+0.1

buffer = processing.runalg("qgis:fixeddistancebuffer", l93['OUTPUT'], 
Dbuf, 100, False, None )

# Dissolve

dissolve = processing.runalg("qgis:dissolve", buffer['OUTPUT'], True, '',  None) 

# Split

split = processing.runalg('qgis:multiparttosingleparts', dissolve['OUTPUT'], None)

#New Fields

rang = processing.runalg('qgis:addfieldtoattributestable', split['OUTPUT'], "Rang", 0, 3, 0, None)

pied = processing.runalg('qgis:addfieldtoattributestable', rang['OUTPUT'], "Pied", 0, 3, 0, None)

# Some steps remaind to code here

# Reproject Layer in WGS84

processing.runalg("qgis:reprojectlayer", pied, "EPSG:4326", output_layer)
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Q&A format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to replace `rang['OUTPUT']` with `rang['OUTPUT_LAYER']` instead as the parameters for the `qgis:addfieldtoattributestable` algorithm reads:

```
>>>processing.alghelp('qgis:addfieldtoattributestable')
ALGORITHM: Add field to attributes table
    INPUT_LAYER <ParameterVector>
    FIELD_NAME <ParameterString>
    FIELD_TYPE <ParameterSelection>
    FIELD_LENGTH <ParameterNumber>
    FIELD_PRECISION <ParameterNumber>
    OUTPUT_LAYER <OutputVector>
```

So instead use:

```
pied = processing.runalg('qgis:addfieldtoattributestable', rang['OUTPUT_LAYER'], "Pied", 0, 3, 0, None)
```

Then when you reproject, use :

```
processing.runalg("qgis:reprojectlayer", pied['OUTPUT_LAYER'], "EPSG:4326", output_layer)
```

Comment: Oh yes, that's it !!
thank you for your help, and now I know where i have to search to solve these type of problems.
I will be able to finish my script, or at least continue.

Comment: @TimothéeColas The best way to say "thank you" here is to upvote and accept the answer.  See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Ok thank you for your advice, i'm a newbie on stackexchange ;)

Comment: @TimothéeColas - Most welcome, glad it helped! And don't worry, you will get quickly used to stackexchange :)